# Are these interchangeable, "I will arrange a meeting for this Friday at 9am" and "I will arrange a meeting for 9am this Friday"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

I am not sure if these sentences are similar

"**I will arrange a meeting for this Friday at 9am**" (1) and "**I will arrange a meeting for 9am this Friday**" (2)?

Let's have a look at the 1st sentence "**I will arrange a meeting for this Friday at 9am**".

I think "**for this Friday**" plays a role of an adjective modifying "**a meeting**" and "**at 9am**" plays a role of an adjective modifying "**this Friday**"

Regarding to the 2nd sentence, "**I will arrange a meeting for 9am this Friday**".

I think "**for 9am**" plays a role of an adjective modifying "**a meeting**" and "**this Friday**" plays a role of an adjective modifying "**9am**".

However, if we say "**I will arrange a meeting this Friday at 9am**" or "**I will arrange a meeting at 9am this Friday**", the meaning changes completely.

That is "**this Friday at 9am**"/"**at 9am this Friday**" is an adverb modifying the verb "**arrange**"

Comment: By using the proposition "for", you've made the sentences clear and synonymous. Without that "for," the expression is ambiguous -- is that when you'll decide the time of the meeting, or is that when the meeting is scheduled?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik. I just want to analyse the sentence, which one modifies which one, very confusing.